# Refactoring bash script that uses several if statements

Tags: bash, shell

I have a bash script that checks if an installation exists and installs it if it doesn't exist based on the path.

Is there a better way to refactor this script so that there isn't as many if statements? So far, I've looked at `if [ -f /usr/bin/go -a -f /usr/bin/python3` but the issue is that the install portion of the script doesn't flow nicely.

```
# chmod 744 to provide execute permissions on this file

echo Installing VIM, Python3, Docker, and Git

# Install VIM
sudo apt install vim
# install the required plugins

# Install Python3 and IDLE
sudo apt update
sudo apt install python3 idle3

# Install Docker but check to see if Docker already exists
if test -f /usr/bin/docker; then
    echo "docker already exists here so I am skipping this intall for you."
else
curl -fsSL https://get.docker.com -o get-docker.sh
sudo sh get-docker.sh
fi
# sudo usermod -aG docker <user-name> to run docker commands without using sudo

# Install Git but check to see if Git already exists
if test -f /usr/bin/git; then
    echo "git already exists here so I am skipping this install for you."
else
    sudo apt install git
fi

# Install Go but check to see if Go already exists
# After installation, review the version and read this blog post https://www.jeremymorgan.com/tutorials/raspberry-pi/install-go-raspberry-pi/
if test -f /usr/bin/go; then
    echo "golange already exists here so I am skipping this install for you."
else
    sudo apt install golang
fi

echo Everything should be installed but check the logs for errors, thank you for your patience.
```

Comment: Questions about suggestions to improve already-working code are generally a better fit for our sister site [codereview.se]. Stack Overflow only permits questions about code that has a *specific problem*, and has been reduced to the shortest possible [mre] that lets someone else reproduce that problem.

Comment: thank you, I will check that site out now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think of something like this, using a *for loop*:

```
exes=( docker git go )
for i in "${!exes[@]}"; do
    if type -p "${exes[i]}" &>/dev/null; then
        echo "${exes[i]} installed"
        unset exes[i]
    else
        echo >&2 "${exes[i]} not installed"
    fi
done

sudo apt install "${exes[@]}"
```